# imread - FileNotFoundError: No such file:

Tags: python, file-not-found, imread

I created a DataGenerator with Sequence class.

```
import tensorflow.keras as keras
from skimage.io import imread
from skimage.transform import resize
import numpy as np
import math
from tensorflow.keras.utils import Sequence

# Here, `x_set` is list of path to the images
# and `y_set` are the associated classes.

class DataGenerator(Sequence):

    def __init__(self, x_set, y_set, batch_size):
        self.x, self.y = x_set, y_set
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def __len__(self):
        return math.ceil(len(self.x) / self.batch_size)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        batch_x = self.x[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) *
        self.batch_size]
        batch_y = self.y[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) *
        self.batch_size]

        return np.array([
            resize(imread(file_name), (224, 224))
               for file_name in batch_x]), np.array(batch_y)
```

Then, I applied this to my training and validation data. `X_train` is a list of strings which contains the image paths to the training data. `y_train` are onehotencoded labels of the training data. The same for validation data.
I applied the DataGenerator to the training and validation data:

```
training_generator = DataGenerator(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32)
validation_generator = DataGenerator(X_val, y_val, batch_size=32)
```

Afterwards I used the `fit_generator` method to run a model:

```
model.fit_generator(generator=training_generator,
                    validation_data=validation_generator,
                    steps_per_epoch = num_train_samples // 32,
                    validation_steps = num_val_samples // 32,
                    epochs = 10,
                    use_multiprocessing=True,
                    workers=2)
```

And got the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-f43ade94ee10> in <module>()
      5                     epochs = 10,
      6                     use_multiprocessing=True,
----> 7                     workers=2)

16 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/imageio/core/request.py in _parse_uri(self, uri)
    271                 # Reading: check that the file exists (but is allowed a dir)
    272                 if not os.path.exists(fn):
--> 273                     raise FileNotFoundError("No such file: '%s'" % fn)
    274             else:
    275                 # Writing: check that the directory to write to does exist

FileNotFoundError: No such file: 'path/to/images/1_1.png'
```

It seems to me that the imread method does not find the file. I checked the image path and it is correct.

Does anyone know what I should change in the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start checking the `x_set` variable (in the instantiation this translates to `X_train`): print out a small slice of this list of image paths e.g.

`print(f"{X_train[:2] = }")`,

then start checking one of these image paths if it exists, and if it is in the same path that you are pointing to from the Python script.

Comment: I checked this and in my opinion, all of the file paths are correct. The files are stored in my Google Drive. If I use this command `!ls "/content/gdrive/My Drive/data/2017-IWT4S-CarsReId_LP-dataset"` all the files and subfolders get listed.  Some of this subfolders contain the images I try to read in with the `DataGenerator`. One path to an image is '/content/gdrive/My Drive/data/2017-IWT4S-CarsReId_LP-dataset/s01_l01/1_1.png'. Could it be that it is because of the storage in Google Drive?

Comment: I noticed that you have a white space in this image path example (/My Drive/). Are you loading it as a raw string into Python? You should. This could be the source of the issue

Comment: Ok, maybe that is the issue but I am not sure if I understand correctly. I did the following to create the whole image paths, because before I only had the paths to the subfolders saved in the list `FileName`, one example in `FileName`was `s01_l01/1_1.png`.  I created a list `FilePath`with this code: `FilePath = []`New line:
`for name in FileName:` New line: `file_path = "/content/gdrive/My Drive/data/2017-IWT4S-CarsReId_LP-dataset/" + name` New Line: `FilePath.append(file_path)`

Comment: Try this modification (notice the r prepending the string): New line: file_path = r"/content/gdrive/My Drive/data/2017-IWT4S-CarsReId_LP-dataset/" + name

Comment: Hmmm... It worked the first time and the model began to learn and the first epoch was initialized. Then I changed the runtime type to GPU and now I get the same error again.... It works without using GPU but with GPU it does not work?

Answer (score 2):

The filename you are using contains [wildcards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_character).
The method **imread** from **opencv** simply doesn't support them.
You need to provide the filename without using wildcards.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I modified the question because actually I do not use wildcards in the filenames but the real file path as stated in my question now. Do you have another idea?